# Shuffle.js breaking when using bootstrap 4, works perfect with 3, need advice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, image-gallery

I am building a website based off of a bootstrap 4 template, and decided to use shuffle.js as the gallery for the site. I followed [this tutorial](http://acasaprogramming.ro/filterable-portfolio-with-shuffle-js-and-bootstrap-3/) from 2015 to achieve [this outcome](http://shufflegallery.surge.sh/), but the gallery tutorial is based off bootstrap 3, and breaks when going into 4 (which I need it to be in for the rest of the website to function properly). I tried researching into the changes from 3 to 4, but couldn't find a fix, and also attempted to check the shuffle update logs, but I don't understand js enough to fix it myself.

Shuffle.js is such a nice gallery, has easy to set up tags and filtering, and I love the way it looks, so really want to get it working on my site. Am hoping someone can help me or point me in the direction of help.

My site I am wanting to implement it on is [here](http://fullsitetest.surge.sh), its a draft with a simple placeholder gallery, but incase anyone needs to see it to help.

Thanks in advance :)

```js
var shuffleme = (function($) {
  'use strict';
  var $grid = $('#grid'), //locate what we want to sort 
    $filterOptions = $('.portfolio-sorting li'), //locate the filter categories
    $sizer = $grid.find('.shuffle_sizer'), //sizer stores the size of the items

    init = function() {

      // None of these need to be executed synchronously
      setTimeout(function() {
        listen();
        setupFilters();
      }, 100);

      // instantiate the plugin
      $grid.shuffle({
        itemSelector: '[class*="col-"]',
        sizer: $sizer
      });
    },



    // Set up button clicks
    setupFilters = function() {
      var $btns = $filterOptions.children();
      $btns.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
          isActive = $this.hasClass('active'),
          group = isActive ? 'all' : $this.data('group');

        // Hide current label, show current label in title
        if (!isActive) {
          $('.portfolio-sorting li a').removeClass('active');
        }

        $this.toggleClass('active');

        // Filter elements
        $grid.shuffle('shuffle', group);
      });

      $btns = null;
    },

    // Re layout shuffle when images load. This is only needed
    // below 768 pixels because the .picture-item height is auto and therefore
    // the height of the picture-item is dependent on the image
    // I recommend using imagesloaded to determine when an image is loaded
    // but that doesn't support IE7
    listen = function() {
      var debouncedLayout = $.throttle(300, function() {
        $grid.shuffle('update');
      });

      // Get all images inside shuffle
      $grid.find('img').each(function() {
        var proxyImage;

        // Image already loaded
        if (this.complete && this.naturalWidth !== undefined) {
          return;
        }

        // If none of the checks above matched, simulate loading on detached element.
        proxyImage = new Image();
        $(proxyImage).on('load', function() {
          $(this).off('load');
          debouncedLayout();
        });

        proxyImage.src = this.src;
      });

      // Because this method doesn't seem to be perfect.
      setTimeout(function() {
        debouncedLayout();
      }, 500);
    };

  return {
    init: init
  };
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function() {
  shuffleme.init(); //filter portfolio
});
```

```css
.portfolio {
  margin: 48px 0;
}

.portfolio-sorting {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
}

.portfolio-sorting li a {
  color: #808080;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px;
}

.portfolio-sorting li a:hover,
.portfolio-sorting li a.active {
  color: #2980b9;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #5A8F39;
  ;
}

.portfolio-item {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <section class="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <ul class="portfolio-sorting list-inline text-center">
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" data-group="all" class="active">All</a></li>
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" data-group="farm">On Farm</a></li>
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" data-group="family">Family</a></li>
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" data-group="historical">Historic</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="portfolio-items list-unstyled" id="grid">

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-groups='["farm"]'>
            <figure class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/YS6QzCN.jpg" alt="Item 1" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-groups='["farm"]'>
            <figure class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FjVfovP.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-groups='["farm"]'>
            <figure class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/R8fVi7p.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-groups='["family"]'>
            <figure class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kvf3NQG.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-groups='["family"]'>
            <figure class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/i53seZh.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-groups='["family"]'>
            <figure class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/y2L2ylu.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-groups='["historical"]'>
            <figure class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JBka7Bu.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-groups='["historical"]'>
            <figure class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3cyOvRe.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-groups='["historical"]'>
            <figure class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JBka7Bu.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-groups='["historical"]'>
            <figure class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1mCAPMW.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-groups='["historical"]'>
            <figure class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1mCAPMW.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-groups='["historical"]'>
            <figure class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D8nQiLn.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-groups='["historical"]'>
            <figure class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pjaGZnu.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" data-groups='["historical"]'>
            <figure class="portfolio-item">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/nMQOVxJ.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 shuffle_sizer"></li>


        </ul>


      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script src="js/jquery.shuffle.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: @WebDevBooster thanks for that suggestion, added in the full code, for some reason it doesn't run fully on the snippet but the entire code is there :)